# Batch: combine txt files in columns

Tags: loops, batch-file

I am trying to merge txt files (from which first column is equal in all) into one file. Thousands of them that I acquire in my experiments. I use 3 input files as an example to illustrate what I am trying to achieve:

```
1.txt     2.txt     3.txt
l1 a1     l1 b1     l1 c1
l2 a2     l2 b2     l2 c2
l3 a3     l3 b3     l3 c3
```

So all input files have the first column in common.
My wish is to get this output:

```
out.txt
l1 a1 b1 c1
l2 a2 b2 c2
l3 a3 b3 c3
```

Attempt 1 of 3

```
:: hmm.bat=============================================
@echo off > hmm.txt & setLocal enableDELAYedeXpansion
echo AAAAAAAAAAaaaaaaaaaa............
pushd %*

for /f "tokens=1* delims= " %%a in (a1.txt) do (
>> hmm.txt echo. %%a hm
)

for %%j in (*.txt) do (
   echo. %%j yes? >> hmm.txt
   for /f "tokens=2* delims= " %%a in (%%j) do (
   >> hmm.txt echo. %%a
   )
)
popd
:: End_Of_Batch======================================
```

This batch file does extract the columns I want, but rather than that everything is in separate columns, all data is in one single column. I have not been able to manage to get output into separate columns.

This attempt (2 of 3) would ultimately give what I want:

```
::=============================================
@echo off > tral.txt & setLocal enableDELAYedeXpansion

set N=
for /f "tokens=1* delims= " %%a in (a1.txt) do (
set /a N+=1 & call :sub1 %%a & set A!N!=!C!
)

set N=
for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%a in (a1.txt) do (
set /a N+=1 & call :sub1 %%a & set B!N!=!C!
)

set N=
for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%a in (a2.txt) do (
set /a N+=1 & call :sub1 %%a & set C!N!=!C!
)

set N=
for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%a in (a3.txt) do (
set /a N+=1 & call :sub1 %%a & set D!N!=!C!
)

for /L %%a in (1 1 !N!) do (
>> tral.txt echo. !A%%a! !B%%a! !C%%a! !D%%a!
)
goto :eof

:sub1 set C to last token
:loop
if '%2' neq '' (
shift
goto :loop
)
set C=%1
goto :eof
::================================================
```

However, to extend this to many (thousands) files, I would need to repeat the bit

```
set N=
for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%a in (a*.txt) do (
set /a N+=1 & call :sub1 %%a & set x!N!=!C!
)
```

maaaaaaaany times. I have tried using a loop instead:

Attempt 3 of 3

```
::=============================================
@echo off & setLocal enableDELAYedeXpansion
type nul > slow.txt

set N=
for /f "tokens=1* delims= " %%a in (a1.txt) do (
set /a N+=1 & call :sub1 %%a & set A!N!=!C!
)

for %%j in (*.txt) do (
set N=
for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%a in (%%j) do (
set /a N+=1 & call :sub1 %%a & set x!N!=!C!
)
)

for /L %%a in (1 1 !N!) do (
>> slow.txt echo. !A%%a! !x%%a!
)
goto :eof

:sub1 set C to last token
:loop
if '%2' neq '' (
shift
goto :loop
)
set C=%1
goto :eof
::=============================================
```

I end up with the first column (which all data files have in common), and the second column of the very last data file.
I do not know how to update the variable x in !x%%a! for each file, to get this printed in a separate column.

Alternatively, does anyone know if it is possible to echo data at the end of a chosen line in the output file?
I would then echo it to the end of the first line, which then would result in echoing all data in columns.
Using

```
set /P line1=< hmm.txt
```

and then

```
echo.%line1% %%a>>hmm.txt
```

does not result in echoing at the end of the first line, but rather at the end of the last line.

Anyone has a solution either way?

Comment: Looks like a database question made with text files where primary key is Column1

Answer (score 1):

In the meantime I have managed to find the solution (with much help from others on http://www.computing.net/answers/programming/merge-files-in-column-output/26553.html).

Perhaps some day someone else has a nice use for this too.

First it counts the files (nr of files is used later on).
The files names without extension are listed in a file "list.dat".

```
@echo off 
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f  %%a in ('dir/b *.txt') do (
    set /a count+=1
    set /a count1=count-1
)
echo total is !count!
echo !count1!

rem empty contents of files
type nul > x.txt
type nul > y.txt
type nul > z.txt
type nul > list.dat

setlocal
set first=y
(
    for /f %%g in ('dir/b/a-d a*.txt') do (
        if defined first (
            set first=
            set/p=%%~ng <nul
        ) else (
            set/p=%%~ng <nul
        )
    )
)>>list.dat

for /f %%j in (list.dat) do (
    echo. %%j   
    for %%a in (%%j) do find /n /v "" < %%a.txt >> x.txt
)
sort x.txt /o x.txt

set "regex=^\[[0-9]\]"
:loop
findstr /r "%regex%" x.txt >> y.txt
if not errorlevel 1 (
    set "regex=^\[[0-9]%regex:~3%
    goto loop
)

set cnt=
set line=
for /f "delims=" %%a in (y.txt) do (
    set input=%%a
    set input=!input:*]=!
    set line=!line! !input!
    if "!cnt!"=="!count1!" (
        >> z.txt echo !line:~1!
        set line=
    )
    set /a cnt=^(cnt + 1^) %% !count!
)

type nul > zz.dat
for /F "delims=" %%i in (z.txt) do (
    set cnt=1
    set rrow=
    for %%j in (%%i) do (
        set /A cnt-=1
        if !cnt! equ 0 (set cnt=0 & set rrow=!rrow! %%j)
    )
    set cnt=2
    set row=
    for %%j in (%%i) do (
        set /A cnt-=1
        if !cnt! equ 0 (set cnt=2 & set row=!row! %%j)
    )
    set row=!row:~1!
    echo. !rrow! !row!>> zz.dat
)

del x.txt
del y.txt
pause
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think BAT programming is appropiate for what you want to acomplish. You might find some convoluted solution, or end up using a third party tool to complement BAT programming (SED comes immediately to my mind) would IMO only add another problem to the equation, either forcing the user to install such a tool, or complicating your BAT distribution and installation with the same intent.

On the other hand, solving your problem is a very easy task to program in *any* general purpouse programming language.

So, I would try either VB or javascript, which are available in almost all windows installations. Take a look at this and get started...

```
@set @junk=1 /*
@echo off
rem textcolumns text
cscript //nologo //E:jscript %0 %*
goto :eof
:allfiles
pushd %1
for /f %%a in ('dir /b /s *.txt') do
  call :coltxt %%a
)
goto :eof
:coltxt
cscript //nologo //E:jscript %*
goto :eof
*/


function openFile(fn) {
 var ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2, ForAppending = 8;
 var TristateUseDefault = -2, TristateTrue = -1, TristateFalse = 0;
 var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
 // Create the file, and obtain a file object for the file.
 // fso.CreateTextFile(fn);
 var f = fso.GetFile(fn);
 // Open a text stream for input.
 ts = f.OpenAsTextStream(ForReading, TristateUseDefault);
 // Read from the text stream and display the results.
 return ts;
}


function removeFirstWord(s) {
  var p1=s.indexOf(" ");
  if (p1>0) {
    return s.substring(p1+1);
  } else {
    return new String();
  }
}

function getCol(ts) {
 var s;
 s = ts.ReadLine();
 s = removeFirstWord(s);
 return s;
}


// main 
x = WScript.Arguments;
fs = new Array(x.length);

for (var i=0; i<x.length; i++) {
 fs[i] = openFile(x(i));
}

while (!fs[0].AtEndOfStream) {
  var s = fs[0].ReadLine();
  for (var i=1; i<fs.length; i++) {
    s += getCol(fs[i]);
  }
  WScript.echo(s);
}

for (var i=0; i<fs.length; i++) {
  fs[i].close();
}
```

Comment: Dear @PA.,
I only just noticed your reply just now. 
I have some previous experience with java, but VB is completely new for me. I will look into that. So far I have found it quite hard to find good learning material for BAT programming. Perhaps for VB this issue may be better.
Eventually I managed to do what I want using BAT programming. Farting around with my data was partially a way to learn some BAT programming too. It was good =)

Comment: Dear @PA. I am starting to play with javascript. I am just wanting to run a 'Hello World' example from the command prompt (windows).
I have saved the following three lines as Hello.js, and am simply trying to run this, so that it will simply print 'Hello World'.  
  
`function helloWorld() {  
  alert('Hello World!') ;  
}`  
  
However, nothing is printed when I type Hello.js or Hello, or cscript Hello.js, or wscript Hello.js at the command prompt.
When I add an error by inserting a random bracket somewhere, it does complain about this.
Can you help me to get started?

Answer (score 0):

If all files have same length:

```
for /f %i in ('find /c /v "" ^< 1.txt') do set n=%i
```

To find number of lines.

Set number of files:

```
set f=4
```

Then read & merge each line:

```
for /l %b in (1,1,%n%) do (
set /p=l%b <nul
for /l %a in (1,1,%f%) do (
for /f "tokens=2" %i in ('find "l%b" ^< %a.txt') do (
set /p=%i <nul
))
echo:
)
```

Sample output:

```
l1 a1 b1 c1 d1
l2 a2 b2 c2 d2
l3 a3 b3 c3 d3
```

Tested on Win 10 CMD

[image: Sample Output]